# Java/Spring: connect to severals BigQuery datasets

Tags: java, spring, google-bigquery

Everything is mostly in the title.
I have an API already connected to a BigQuery dataset, which is regularly queried. Soon, my process will necessitate new data stocked in another BigQuery dataset.

So, I started to check if it's possible to connect to two different BQ datasets to one Spring API. Unless I missed it, I didn't find any information for this specific case inside BQ documentation.

As the API is already connected, the properties values of `spring.cloud.gcp.bigQuery.*` are already defined. As such, I can't use those properties to define the new connection.

So is it possible to connect one API to several BigQuery datasets ? if so, how can I do that with the properties files ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not achieve what you are after doing something like:

```
public BigQuery bigQuery1() {
 return BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
    .setCredentials(
       ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
         new FileInputStream("your_json_service_keyfile.json"))
    )
    .setProjectId("bigQuery1")
    .build().getService();
}


public BigQuery bigQuery2() {
 return BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
    .setCredentials(
       ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
         new FileInputStream("your_json_service_keyfile.json"))
    )
    .setProjectId("bigQuery2")
    .build().getService();
}
```